# If $AB-I$ is regular, then $BA-I$ is regular

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I prove that if $AB-I$ is regular $BA-I$ is regular?
I proved it only if $A$ or $B$ is regular.
if $A$ is irregular:
$$
\implies \det(AB-I) = \det(A(B-A^{-1})) = \det(A)\det(B-A^{-1}) \\
= \det(B-A^{-1})\det(A)=\det((B-A^{-1})A)=\det(BA-I) \implies
$$
because $AB-I$ is irregular $\det(AB-I) = \det(BA-I) != 0$ so $BA-I$ is regular,same if $B$ is regular.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint.** If $(AB-I)x=0$ for some $x\ne0$, what is $(BA-I)(Bx)$? Can $Bx$ be zero?

Comment: can you show me the solution?

Comment: ?????????????????????????????????

Comment: @user146701 Why don't you try to solve it first? If $(AB-I)x=0$, then $ABx=x$, so $(BA-I)(Bx)=...$

Comment: if (BA-I)x = 0 <=> BAx = x <=> ABAx = Ax <=> (AB-I)(Ax) = 0,because (AB-I) invertible => Ax = 0 but because BAx = x => x = 0. is there a way to prove that if Ax = 0 => x = 0 without going back to BAx = x?

Comment: Very nice indeed.

Comment: @user146701 Huh? Why would you want to prove that "Ax = 0 => x = 0"? This is not what the question asks for. The question asks you to prove that if $AB-I$ is singular, then $BA-I$ is singular. Now, recall that a square matrix $M$ is singular if and only if $Mv=0$ for some $v\ne0$. Therefore, in this question, it suffices to show that if $(AB-I)x=0$ for some $x\ne0$, then $(BA-I)y=0$ for some $y\ne0$.

Comment: no the problem is to prove that if AB-I is invertible BA-I is invertible

Comment: @user146701 Sigh. First, the rare term "[regular matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_matrix)" refers to an invertible matrix, and hence an irregular matrix means a singular matrix. Second, if you do want to prove that $BA-I$ is invertible whenever $AB-I$ is invertible, you may prove by contradiction: if $BA-I$ is singular, then $AB-I$ must also be singular. To prove this, just interchange the roles of $A$ and $B$ in my answer.

Comment: I have already proved it. 
if (BA-I)x = 0 <=> BAx = x <=> ABAx = Ax <=> (AB-I)(Ax) = 0,because (AB-I) invertible => Ax = 0 but because BAx = x => x = 0

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, a possible answer comes from the more general fact

> Let $A$ be a unital ring, and $a, b \in A$. Then $1 - a b$ is invertible if and only if $1 - b a$ is invertible.

Suppose $1 - a b$ is invertible. Then $ (1 - b a) b  = b - b a b = b (1 - ab)$. So $b$ is in the right ideal $I$ generated by $1 - ba$, and thus $b a \in I$, so that $1 = (1 - ba) + ba \in I$, and thus $1 - ba$ is right invertible. A similar argument, starting with $a (1 - ba)$, shows that $1 - ba$ is left invertible, and thus invertible.

Explicitly, $b = (1 - ba) b (1-ab)^{-1}$, so $1 = (1 - ba) + (1 - ba) b (1-ab)^{-1} a$, and thus
$$
1 = (1 - ba) (1 + b (1-ab)^{-1} a),
$$
that is,
$$
(1 - ba)^{-1} =  1 + b (1-ab)^{-1} a.
$$

Comment: The informal argument is $$(1-ba)^{-1}=1+ba+baba+bababa+\cdots=1+b(1+ab+abab+\cdots)a=1+b(1-ba)^{-1}a$$ which I always like to use to remember this.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff, excellent remark, thanks! And kudos on your avatar ;-)

Comment: We both wrote $ba$ in the second inverse, when it should be $ab$. =)

Comment: @PedroTamaroff, thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Since you proved it for $A$ invertible so in the general case use the density of $GL_n(\Bbb R)$ in $M_n(\Bbb R)$ and the continuity of the determinant.

Comment: I don't know what is the density of GL(R) in M(R)

Comment: So prove it before!

Comment: I don't know what is the meaning of:density of GL(R) in M(R)

Comment: Do you never hear before  that $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$?

Comment: probably I didn't

Answer (score 1):

I prove this for general $A$ and $B$. We assume that $A$ and $B$ are respectively $n\times m$ and $m\times n$ matrices. $I_n$ represents the identity matrix of size $n\times n$ Consider the following matrix $M$ defined as follows:
$$
M=\left[\begin{matrix}
I_{n}&A\\
B&I_m
\end{matrix}\right]
$$
By changing the rows and columns of the matrix $M$ we can arrive at the following Matrix:
$$
M'=\left[\begin{matrix}
I_m&B\\
A&I_n
\end{matrix}\right]
$$
The only thing that matters is that by doing this, we can say the following things about the determinant of $M$ and $M'$:
$$
\mid \det(M)\mid=\mid \det(M')\mid.
$$
Now using [Schur complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement) of $M$ and $M'$ we can see :
$$
\det(M)=\det(I_n-AB)\\
\det(M')=\det(I_m-BA).
$$
Therefore we have:
$$
\mid \det(I_n-AB)\mid=\mid \det(I_m-BA)\mid
$$
which proves what you want.

Answer (score 0):

**Preface.** You have proved the equality $\det(AB-I) = \det(BA-I)$ for all cases when $A$ is regular (I'll use the term *invertible* instead), and you want to extend it to the case of an arbitrary $A$. There are standard ways to do such generalizations.

One way is hinted at in Sami Ben Romdhane's answer. Another way could be the algebraic analogue of it: the algebraic variety generated by $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ is $\operatorname{M}(\mathbb{R})$, therefore any polynomial identity that holds for all invertible matrices must hold for all matrices, both invertible and singular. What follows is an implementation of that idea, but in more elementary terms.

**Proposed solution.** Pick two arbitrary matrices $A_0$ and $B$. Also, pick some *invertible* matrix $A_1$. Now let us denote $A(t) = (1-t)A_0 + tA_1$. You can think of $A(t)$ as a straight line in the "space of all matrices". At $t=0$ we have $A(0) = A_0$, at $t=1$ we have $A(1) = A_1$.

Now, let's look at these two functions:
$$
\begin{align}
P(t) &= \det A(t) \\
Q(t) &= \det(A(t)B-I) - \det(BA(t) - I)
\end{align}
$$

Here are some observations about them:

1. Both $P(t)$ and $Q(t)$ are polynomials of $t$ (do you understand why?).
2. At $t=1$ we have $P(1) = \det A_1 \neq 0$. Also, $Q(1) = \det(A_1B-I) - \det(BA_1 - I) = 0$ (this follows from your work, since $A_1$ is invertible).
3. At $t=0$ we have $Q(0) = \det(A_0B-I) - \det(BA_0-I)$. What we want to prove is that $Q(0)=0$.

Let us concentrate on $P(t)$ first. We know that it is a polynomial, and that it is not zero (because $P(1) \neq 0$). It is known that a nonzero polynomial on $\mathbb{R}$ can only have a finite number of roots (it is bounded by the degree of the polynomial). So, $P(t) = 0$ only for finitely many $t$. Then $P(t) \neq 0$ for all $t$ in an infinite set $T \subseteq \mathbb{R}$.

Now let us look at $Q(t)$. Whenever $t \in T$, we have $P(t) = \det A(t) \neq 0$, so the matrix $A(t)$ is invertible for each $t \in T$. But then we have $Q(t) = \det(A(t)B-I) - \det(BA(t)-I) = 0$ (you have proved this). We see that polynomial $Q(t)$ has infinitely many roots! This is only possible if $Q(t)=0$ for every $t \in \mathbb{R}$. So in fact the equality
$$
\det(A(t)B-I) = \det(BA(t)-I)
$$
holds for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. At $t=0$ we have $\det(A_0B-I) = \det(BA_0-I)$, as required.

Comment: Why should $A$ and $B$ be square matrices?

Comment: @egreg the OP takes determinants of $A$, so I assumed it is square. He also uses the same letter $I$ on both sides of the equation. I would expect to see something like $I_n$ and $I_m$ there if $A$ and $B$ weren't square.

Comment: The OP is doing wrong, I believe. See user1551's solution: nice and clean.